# How does $\left[\nabla f\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\right]^\mathrm{T} \nabla f\left(\mathbf{x}\right)$ approximate $\mathbf{H}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, optimization, approximation

Page 3 of [a guide to Levenberg-Marquardt optimization](https://www.cs.nyu.edu/~roweis/notes/lm.pdf) says that $\left[\nabla f\left(\mathbf{x}\right)\right]^\mathrm{T} \nabla f\left(\mathbf{x}\right)$ approximates the Hessian matrix of $f$. I do not understand this at all. How does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\phi(x) = f(x)^2$, where $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.

Then ${\partial^2 \phi(x) \over \partial x^2} = 2 \left( f(x){\partial^2 f(x) \over \partial x^2} + {\partial f(x) \over \partial x}^T {\partial f(x) \over \partial x} \right)$.

Gauss Newton methods approximate ${\partial^2 \phi(x) \over \partial x^2}$ by the term
$2{\partial f(x) \over \partial x}^T {\partial f(x) \over \partial x}$,
and
Levenberg Marquardt methods approximate ${\partial^2 \phi(x) \over \partial x^2}$ by the term 
$2 \left( f(x)D + {\partial f(x) \over \partial x}^T {\partial f(x) \over \partial x} \right)$ where $D>0$ is typically some diagonal matrix.